# Inconsistent augmentation results for masks and images while flipping in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-augmentation

I am currently trying to implement my own function to do paired data augmentation in `tensorflow`. To do this, I need to apply random image transformations to the input image and relevant transformations to the output mask (i.e. rotations and flipping). However, image flipping/reversing is not working as appropriate. A code example of what I have at the moment is as follows:

```
def paired_data_augmentation(image_masks_tuple):
    #the image_masks_tuple contains an image as its first
    #and masks as the remaining elements
    def flipper(image_masks,mode = 'lr'):
        image = image_masks[0]
        masks = image_masks[1:]
        if mode == 'lr':
            image_masks = [
                tf.reverse(m,[0]) for m in image_masks]
        elif mode == 'ud':
            image_masks = [
                tf.reverse(m,[1]) for m in image_masks]
        image = image_masks[0]
        masks = image_masks[1:]
        return [image,*new_masks]

    image = image_masks_tuple[0]
    masks = image_masks_tuple[1:]
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)

    flip_lr = tf.random_uniform([])
    flip_ud = tf.random_uniform([])

    tmp = [image,*masks]

    tmp = tf.cond(
        tf.greater_equal(flip_lr,0.5),
        lambda: flipper(tmp,mode = 'lr'),
        lambda: tmp)
    set_shape(tmp)
    tmp = tf.cond(
        tf.greater_equal(flip_ud,0.5),
        lambda: flipper(tmp,mode = 'ud'),
        lambda: tmp)
    set_shape(tmp)

    return tmp
```

What I was expecting this to do was to flip all images/masks in the same way if `flip_lr > 0.5` or `flip_ud > 0.5`, but what is actually happening is that some images will be flipped without the masks getting flipped and v/v. Has someone experienced this and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As per the following lines code:

```
        if mode == 'lr':
            image_masks = [
                tf.reverse(m,[0]) for m in image_masks]
        elif mode == 'ud':
            image_masks = [
                tf.reverse(m,[1]) for m in image_masks]
```

you are applying augmentation only to the masks. If your task is segmentation then whatever augmentation you are applying to the mask should be applied to the groundtruth image also.

I found the following implementation easier :

```
def flip_image_vertically(image, mask):
    """Randomly flip an image and label vertically (left to right).
    """
    uniform_random = tf.random_uniform([], 0, 1.0)
    flip_cond = tf.less(uniform_random, .5)
    image = tf.cond(flip_cond, lambda: tf.image.flip_up_down(image), lambda: image)
    mask = tf.cond(flip_cond, lambda: tf.image.flip_up_down(mask), lambda: mask)

    return image, mask
```

what it does:

1. Generates a random floating point scalar between 0 and 1.
2. iff greater than **.5** then flip both images and masks

you can also use **[tf.image.flip_left_right](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/flip_left_right)** for horizontal flipping.

**[tf.image.flip_up_down](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/flip_up_down)**

Comment: `image_masks` contains both image and masks. Your solution does the same as mine in a clear way, which is why I upvote it. But the weird behaviour is still there (they get flipped differently). But thank you either way!